# Returning URL-info as strings?

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I'm trying to write a simple django-view that returns any 'input' given from the url-field as raw text:

But i'm having a real hard time to make my reg-ex accept special chars.

Code: views.py

```
def urlinfo(request,info):

    return HttpResponse(str(info), content_type="text/plain")
```

urls.py

```
  url(r'^urlinfo/(?P<info>[\w\+\?-_=+&]+)', urlinfo),
```

What i'm looking for is the possibilty to enter urls, like .../urlinfo/name=Joe&age=20

and then, later on, have my views hande it properly. But as of now, i can't get pass the reg-ex..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

name=joe&age=20 are GET parameter, which usually are entered via forms, or just append to a link. You dont need a regex for them, they are stored in request.GET dictionary.

Comment: Sometimes it's just to easy. Sorry.